# Get array items inside a mongodb document

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb

I have this kind of document:

For this _id, I want to get all events with "events.time" > time1 (and only these ones):

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "events": [
        {"time": 345678, "value": "1"},
        {"time": 567890, "value": "2"},
        ...
    ]
}
```

How can I do ? Is there an easy way to extract data from an array inside a mongodb document ?
(I use python 2.7 and mongod v2.2.4)

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You should accept some answers if you want people to keep answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution in my case seemed to choose another schema for my database.
So I created a separate event collection...

Answer (score 1):

While you can find documents based on the contents of subdocument arrays, mongo will return the entire document.

Unless there are tons of events and you can't spare the network traffic, you'll have an easier time filtering the array on the client, in Python.

Probably it's more trouble than it's worth, but if you really want to filter the documents on the server, you can do it using the aggregation framework. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14157118/893113).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a lot of events yes.
I get the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'"
I suppose it comes from $project part but I don't find how to solve it... An idea ?

Comment: I'm finally going to change my database structure. I'm creating a event database. I think it will be a more natural usage of mongo and more efficient way to do that.
Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, an events collection is probably a better fit for what you're wanting to accomplish.