# Mongodb. Method to limit subdocuments that only have the given fields of the `projection` (that is, filter)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Because there is no way to filter subdocuments in MongoDB (reference: [How to select subdocuments with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861938/how-to-select-subdocuments-with-mongodb) )

Is there another way/method within MongoDB to quickly drop/filter fields that don't have the given field, that don't have the `subdocument` field in the example below?

Is the only way to do this by processing the result **outside** of mongodb and filter out all empty documents?

(Imagine a situation when you have a thousand subdocs with varying schemas. I do a .find() and get the 1000 subdocs, but 900 are empty. I just want to get the 100, so I'm not always having to process and drop the empty ones outside MongoDB.)

For example, you have this JSON that is in a `collection named monday`:

```
{
document : [
            {
             subdocument : "Hello World"
            },
            {
             subdocument : "Hello Moon"
            },
            {
             another_field: "Hello Sun"
            }
            ]
}
```

And you make this query `db.monday.find({},{_id:0,"document.subdocument":1})`

The result will be:

```
    { "document" : [    
    {   "subdocument" : "Hello World" },    
    {   "subdocument" : "Hello Moon" },     
    {    } 
    ] }
```

You see the another_field is still returned although as empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that empty fields are returned in this case because document is an array and Mongodb does not want to change the array index of any elements.

You can get an array of subdocuments with the aggregation framework:

```
db.monday.aggregate(
  [
    { $match: 
      {'document.subdocument' : 
        { $exists: 1 }
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$document" }, 
    { $match: 
      {'document.subdocument' : 
        { $exists: 1 }
      }
    },
    { $project: { subdocument: "$document.subdocument", _id: 0 } }
  ])
```

Yields:

```
 [
    {
        "subdocument" : "Hello World"
    },
    {
        "subdocument" : "Hello Moon"
    }
 ]
```

The first `$match` is not necessary, it just speeds up the processing if there are a lot of documents that do not have any of the subdocuments you are looking for.

Comment: Yeh, you're completely right. Mongodb doesn't want to change an index. What I want is database side filter to get only the subdocuments. Imagine a situation when you have a thousand subdocs with varying schemas. I do a db.monday.find() and get the 1000 subdocs, but 900 are empty. I just want to get the 100, so I'm not always having to process and drop the empty ones.

Comment: Answer updated to only return the subdocuments.  Remove the `$project` if you want the document IDs along with them.  (See revision 2 of this answer.)

Comment: Simply great! I just tested. (I have to explore the aggregation framework more now.)