# Return document and only matching subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for similar behavior to $elemMatch, but I need only matching subdocuments returned.  Doing filtering in my application would be difficult since I am using $nearSphere for matching subdocuments.  Is there any known workarounds to Mongo's limitation of only returning the first matching subdocument?

For example:

```
var office = new Schema({ name: String, location: [Number] });
var company = new Schema({ name: String, offices: [office] });
```

How can I go about finding companies and local offices?  I'm open to other ideas beyond my specific and ideal solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select subdocuments with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861938/how-to-select-subdocuments-with-mongodb)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB extract only the selected item in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array)